# ¿Como guardo dinámicamente un valor en un td de un table?

Tags: javascript, table

les detallo mi problema, estoy construyendo un tabla mediante JavaScrip y con esto no tengo ningún problema, ya lo tengo en marcha, pero lo que necesito es guardarme un valor dentro de los tags tds para luego, si recorro todos los tds de la tabla, poder contar con los ids de los elementos que puse en la tabla. Por algún lado vi que se puede hacer, pero, siempre hay un pero, no recuerdo el como, razón por la cual les pido ayuda.

Sería algo así

```
<tr>
   <td clave=1>Item_1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td clave=2>Item_2</td>
</tr>
```

Desde ya, muchas gracias y aguardo alguna pista por donde continuar mi búsqueda.

Comment: ¿Quieres recorrer los tds de la tabla e irle asignando un id consecutivo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay una opción que puedes usar la cual es [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/como/Usando_atributos_de_datos) , es accesible de forma nativa desde HTML o desde javascript.
A el elemento le añades la opción `data-identificador="valor"`.

Y desde el javascript accedes de forma `element.dataset.identificador`, tanto para asignar como para consultar.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    añadeitem(3);
    añadeitem(4);

    var ids = [];
    var tabla = document.getElementById('tabla');
    for (const row of tabla.rows) {
        ids.push(row.cells[0].dataset.clave);
    }
    console.log(ids);
});

function añadeitem(id) {
    var tabla = document.getElementById('tabla');
    var row = tabla.insertRow();
    var cell = row.insertCell();
    cell.dataset.clave = id;
    cell.innerText = "item " + id;
}
```

```css
#tabla, td{
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<TABLE id="tabla" >
        <tr>
            <td data-clave="1">Item_1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-clave="2">Item_2</td>
        </tr>
    </TABLE>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, era justamente lo que estaba buscando y no recordaba como hacerlo.